# How to change python version in Anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to get into deep learning. I installed Anaconda to use jupyter and generally not to care about installing all of those packages like matplotlib etc myself. But I cannot install tensorflow as it works only with Python  3.4, 3.5, or 3.6 but I have 3.7. After I read about it I installed python 3.6.8. I uninstalled Anaconda and installed it again, nothing changed. After that, I used this command

> conda install python=3.6.8

to presumably install python 3.6.8 for it (I found this solution somewhere on the web). The command worked but didn't change anything. Please help

Comment: Everytime i use "!pip install --upgrade tensorflow" in jupyter i get:
Collecting tensorflow

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: tensorflow is not released yet to  Python 3.7

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A better (recommended) alternative is to create a virtual environment of the desired Python version and then use that environment to run Tensorflow and other scripts.

To do that, you can follow the instructions given [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands).

**BUT**, if you don't want to create a separate environment, then `conda install python=<version>` should do.

**OR** (not recommended) you can download the "latest" Anaconda installer with your required Python version bundled.

[Source](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#getting-anaconda)

Comment: I run conda install python and this is its final output: 
python-3.6.8         | 20.3 MB   | ########################################################## | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-build-3.17.6-py37_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')

Comment: That's a permission error. Try running the command with admin privileges. If you're on Unix, add a `sudo` behind the command. If on Windows, run the Anaconda Shell as an admin. As a side-note, refrain from installing Anaconda and Python in the root directory.

Comment: I did. But a few errors showed up (tho there was more info about things that were installed), those are errors that popped out:
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): ...
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::notebook-5.7.4-py37_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')
Attempting to roll back.

Comment: DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\ProgramData...', 'C:\\ProgramData...', '--reset']
done
PermissionError(13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process')

Comment: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. You should terminate that process, and then restart installing Python. If you don't know which process it is, you can reboot your computer, so that it terminates itself, and then install your required Python version.

Comment: I rebooted my pc and it worked! Thank you very much! I have been struggling with this for quite some time!!!

Answer (score 7):

Sometime command is not working as expected I was also facing same issue when I
used this command.

```
conda install python=<version>
```

then I have changed the Python version with the help of anaconda Navigator. I have create new enviornment and follow below instruction=>

1. In Navigator, click the Environments tab, then click the Create button. The Create new environment dialog box appears.
2. In the Environment name field, type a descriptive name for your environment.

3.In the Packages list select “Python” and in the Python version list select the version you want to use.

4.Click the Create button.

5.Navigator creates the new environment and activates it, as shown by the highlighted green bar. All actions take place in the active environment.

for more details please go through this link =>
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/use-multiple-python-versions/

Answer (score 2):

By default, the conda environment will use the python version 3.7, since you installed Anaconda with python3.7.

You would need to create a symbolic link to the new version of the python (in your case python3.6.8) using

```
ln -s ~/anaconda3/bin/<python3.6.8>
```

(you may need to replace 'python3.6.8' with the appropriate file name).

Another, better way would be to create a new environment in conda and then use python3.6.8 as you would like. Follow steps at https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands  to create an environment.

For python3.6.8, run the following command:

```
conda create -n <myenv> python=3.6.8
```

(replace 'myenv' with the name of your new environment)

After that, activate the environment with :

```
conda activate <myenv>
```

Comment: I followed these steps and activated the new environment. Somehow `python -V` still shows 3.7.3 and not the requested (and installed) python version.

Answer (score 1):

You just can change the python version by creating a new environment in anaconda.
It will ask for the python version when you create an environment

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of the macOS 10.14.6. I degrade the python version from 3.7.4 to 3.7.0 in Anaconda and it works. Here I share my solution. I solve this question in other website. Check the answer by clicking here(https://www.udemy.com/course/the-python-mega-course/learn/lecture/4775342#questions/11049798).

Answer (score -3):

The most pain-free approach that worked for me was to install the legacy version of Anaconda. If you want Python 3.6 as default, I recommand downloading Anaconda 5.2.0 which was the last version to use Python 3.6 in base environment as default. (Legacy versions can be found [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/).)

If you also want the latest version of Anaconda, there is an easy way. With Anaconda 5.2.0 installed, you can actually update to newer versions of Anaconda by

```
conda update anaconda
```

which will try to update all your packages except keepping Python at 3.6.x.